# Is there an IF condition in htaccess for current session_user_name?

Tags: php, .htaccess

All currently logged in users have a Session with their role.
For example I use `SESS_ROLE = 2` for users and `SESS_ROLE = 3` for companies.

My goal is to have `domain.com/profile` for both roles. So my question is, is there a way to do it?

Does htaccess have something like `if ( sess_role == 2) { .... } else { ... }` ?
Or can you suggest me a workaround ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/profile/?$ /profile/company.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/profile/?$ /profile/user.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP session data is not generally visible to Apache, EXCEPT for the session ID in the session cookie.

You can use a [rewrite map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to link a PHP script to a rewrite directive, however, which would let this PHP script expose session data to Apache.

Comment: Truly thank you for this. Instead of this, do you think is there a workaround without using htaccess? I can't think of any.

Comment: You could do it in php, and simply include the appropriate based on what profile should be loaded.

Comment: Damn, so simple. I did it with `header` and showed the file at the end but I didn't thought of this :P . I accepted the answer.